# How can I save the standard Yum output to a variable from the Python Yum API?

Tags: python, yum

For example:

```
>>> import yum
>>> y = yum.YumBase()
>>> x = {'release': '11.el7', 'epoch': '', 'version': '3.10', 'arch': 'x86_64', 'name': 'PyYAML'}
>>> y.install(**x)
Package PyYAML-3.10-11.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by python2-pyyaml-5.1.2-1.0.1.el7.x86_64 which is already installed
[]
```

What's returned here is the empty list. Is there a clean way to assign the standard yum message to a variable?

Comment: Can you update the question with expected output?

Comment: It's already there. I want to assign the standard yum output to a variable.

Comment: Are you looking for  `var = y.install(**x)`?

Comment: No. "What's returned here is the empty list". I want to capture the yum message output displayed above the returned value. Ideally in a clean manner through the actual api

Comment: something like this in this case? `var = "Package PyYAML-3.10-11.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by python2-pyyaml-5.1.2-1.0.1.el7.x86_64 which is already installed
"`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this messages are [generated via logging](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/yum/blob/master/yum/__init__.py#L5002). One way to get these messages is to [redirect `stderr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stderr) of the function call to a buffer.

```
>>> import logging
>>> import io
>>> from contextlib import redirect_stderr
>>>
>>> def install():
...     logging.warning("Some Message")
...     return []
...
>>> f = io.StringIO()
>>>
>>> with redirect_stderr(f):
...     result = install()
...
>>> print("Functon Result: ", result)
Functon Result:  []
>>> print("Function messages::", f.getvalue())
Function Warning messages:: WARNING:root:Some Message
```